# Target specific NSTextField in NSCellView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm a bit stuck, again . . .

I have an NSTableView with some custom NSTableCellView, one of which contains a couple of NSTextFields.

Now, i would like to modify the values being displayed in some of the fields, so have created overwritten the create cell function as follows:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    // Get a new ViewCell
    NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
```

I am then using the following code to target specific columns:

```
if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"Tweets"]){
         NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        //Set predicate and filter for New tweets page
        if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"new"]) {
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == NO) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"postDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        //Set filter and predicate for the Approved tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"approved"]){
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(approved == YES) AND (tweetDeleted == NO)  AND (scheduledTweet == NO)"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"approvedDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"deleted"]){
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tweetDeleted == YES"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"deletedDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        //Set filter and preicate for the Deleted tweets page
    } else if ([self.currentTwitterView isEqualToString:@"scheduled"]){
        NSPredicate *testForTrue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scheduledTweet == YES"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scheduledDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
        [request setPredicate:testForTrue];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }
    //Setup the Request
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tweet" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];

    //Assign the predicate to the fetch request
    NSError *error = nil;

    //Create an array from the returned objects
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    Tweet *selectedTweet = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:row];

    [cellView.textField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Access granted for %@", selectedTweet.scheduledDate]];

    return cellView;
```

However, i can't for the life of me work out how to target each specific TextField in the cell, if i create an IBOutlet then i get an error about there being multiple (which makes sense) but if i don't do that, then there is no way to access it that i can see.

I have looked at the apple class docs, and it doesn't really elaborate either.

Help greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH14-SW5

Has all the info you need in it.

Specifically the section marked:

```
Acquiring a Cell from Interface Builder
```